# How do i assign a new disk/LV to the root folder "/" which has been already mounted by sdb2 partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, disk

```
[root@my-linux-vm ~]# lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                   2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda                   8:0    0   16G  0 disk
└─sda1                8:1    0   16G  0 part
sdb                   8:16   0   10G  0 disk
├─sdb1                8:17   0    2M  0 part
└─sdb2                8:18   0   10G  0 part /
sdc                   8:32   0   12G  0 disk
└─sdc1                8:33   0   12G  0 part
  └─vg_new_root-lv0 252:0    0   11G  0 lvm
sr0                  11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Given the above partition/disk situation,
can i mount the 'vg_new_root-lv0' LV onto the root ("/")folder in order to extend the root capacity beyond sdb2 space?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is `No, based on your current configuration`.
Due to the fact that the `/` root filesystem is not part of LVM there is no easy way to expand its capacity.
My suggestion would be to run a disk space script to confirm what is the directory or service that is using a significant amount of the disk space and then (if possible) move that data into the new `sdc1 drive / vg_new_root-lv0 Logical Volume`, it needs to be formatted and mounted to be ready to use, once mounted you can stop your application and then move all the data to that new filesystem (i.e /mnt/data), after you confirm that the data has been moved you can then start your application, test and then remove the data from the original location under the `sdb2 disk / root / filesystem` to free up space.
Run the below one liner to get a disk usage report and confirm what you can remove / compress / move.

```
echo -n "Type Filesystem: ";read FS;NUMRESULTS=20;resize;clear;date;df  -h $FS;echo "Largest Directories:"; du -x $FS 2>/dev/null| sort  -rnk1| head -n $NUMRESULTS| awk '{printf "%d MB %s\n", $1/1024,$2}';echo  "Largest Files:"; nice -n 19 find $FS -mount -type f -ls  2>/dev/null| sort -rnk7| head -n $NUMRESULTS|awk '{printf "%d  MB\t%s\n", ($7/1024)/1024,$NF}'
```